# Do the different editions of Roll for It contain different cards?

Tags: edition-comparison

Roll for It comes in (at least) 3 different editions - red, purple, and deluxe. Red and purple each have 30 cards, while the deluxe edition comes with 60 cards. Do the different editions have completely different sets of cards, or is there some overlap between them? Are the red and purple editions identical except for the color of the cards?

Answer (score 2):

According to [BoardgameGeek](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/129090/roll-it)

> There are two sets of Roll For It! available -- the red set comes with
> translucent dice and the purple set comes with pearl dice. There are
> no duplicate cards between the sets. Each set allows play for 2-4
> players, but when they are combined, up to eight players can compete
> in the same game of Roll For It!

Since it does not mention the deluxe version, my guess would be that it is just the combined version of red and purple for 8 players